# Render images with no extension in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm sending emails through .net core C# (SmtpClient). The body of the mails is HTML. In the most of the templates I got images . For some reason some of the images used in the templates don't have an extension (e.g. .jpeg, .png ect...) for example

```
<img src="https://www.somedomain.com/images/myimage" />
```

When I open the received email in Outlook no images are displayed. I viewed the source of the outlook mail and it turned out the "src" attribute has been replaced with "defang_src" -
`<img alt="myimage" defang_src="https://www.somedomain.com/images/myimage">`

So it doesnt display the image or anything at all of course.

Does anyone knows what exactly happens with Outlook and how can I avoid this issue? 
Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Same here, mail sent from sendinblue platform

Comment: Which version (2016, 2019 etc) and platform (Windows, Mac etc) is it?